# Spring Cloud Gateway Memory Leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

Memory leak was found in spring cloud gateway in production which caused downtime of the system.

The memory usage kept increasing until it ran out of the memory which caused the follow exceptions:

```
2019-05-21 09:18:24.793 WARN The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1301)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:578)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1049)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:985)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:830)
    at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2459)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

2019-05-21 09:18:24.792 WARN An exception 'io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2046820359, max: 2058354688)' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:

io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2046820359, max: 2058354688)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:655)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:610)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:769)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:745)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:244)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:226)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.reallocate(PoolArena.java:397)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.capacity(PooledByteBuf.java:120)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureWritable0(AbstractByteBuf.java:299)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureWritable(AbstractByteBuf.java:278)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1103)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1096)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1087)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder$1.cumulate(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

spring-boot-version: **2.1.3.RELEASE**

spring-cloud-version: **Greenwich.SR1**

reactor-netty: **0.8.5.RELEASE**

Does anyone know the root cause of this issue or are there any fixes?

What does the **Tag mismatch** error mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be a bug report to the Spring Cloud team.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm voting not to close this question. While I agree on this being a bug report, let me ask the following: how many "bug report" solutions have you read on SO? I think SO is a great place to ask the community instead of dev teams about existing problems

Comment: I would recommend you to try the latest versions available.